# Как сделать примерное равняется на Js?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
if (e.name ==  vasya) {
    // выполняем что то
}
```

так вот допустим `e.name` это "Василий" так вот а "vasya" равняется "василий петрович" так вот в данном коде функция сработает только если оно идеально равняется "Василий" а как сделать так что бы срабатывало если не идеально символ в символ а как там, с маленькой буквой и еще и фамилией?

Comment: надо использовать регулярные выражения

Comment: дайте пример кода, который подошел бы в данной ситуации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1 (с использованием indexOf):**

```
var name = 'Василий';
var value = 'василий петрович';

var _name = name.toLowerCase();
var _value = value.toLowerCase();

if (_value.indexOf(_name) != -1) {
    alert('Found!');
}
```

**Вариант 2 (с использованием регулярных выражений):**

```
var name = 'Василий';
var value = 'василий петрович';

name = name.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

var needle = new RegExp(name, 'ig');

if (needle.test(value)) {
    alert('Found!');
}
```

Comment: `new RegExp(name, 'ig');` - только этого не хватало.

Comment: А как бы Вы написали?

Comment: Во-первых, зачем превращать имя в регулярку? Во-вторых, а кто символы экранировать будет?

Comment: e.name - скорее всего "динамическая" переменная, а создание регулярного выражения с использованием переменных возможно только таким образом. По поводу экранирования согласен. Исправлю

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методами [String.match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) или [String.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp) для поиска  в строке.

Comment: попробовал, что то у меня не получается, дайте пример кода именно для данной ситуации